# centos 7 mainnet fullnode disk read overload

Tags: nodeos

```
OS: CentOS 7
kernel: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
eos version: v1.6.0
DISK IOPS: 20000+
```

high IO read caused sync exception. need help, please!!

[image]

Comment: Can you add a few more details, such as what the full command you are running is, the exact error message, etc.?

Comment: run cmd: nodeos --data-dir /data/eos-mainnet --config-dir /data/eos-mainnet,config.ini: `https://gist.github.com/colinlabs/f3829b00cf041157a334e1ebac85ed41`. there is no error message. just high io read and  %idle ~ 99%

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in `nodeos`, but in the config file I see:

```
# mainnet
filter-on = eosio::
filter-on = kofoatomicsw::
filter-on = eosio.token::
```

To me, this indicates that you should record all actions from `eosio`, `eosio.token`, and `kofoatomicsw`.
Obviously, `eosio` and `eosio.token` are used constantly by anyone who is using the main net, and this might be the cause for your high IO. Try removing those filters and seeing if it improves, and if so then you'll have to think carefully about how to apply filters in order to get only the information you really need, or improve your server to deal with the higher IO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, solved with comment

```
filter-on = eosio::
filter-on = eosio.token::
```